# Writing in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I want to save usernames and user scores in a JSON file, currently I have a JSON file looking like this which I manually wrote for testing and it's looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "username": "Testing",
        "score": 2
    },
    {
        "username": "Testing123",
        "score": 3
    }
]
```

I can now read from this file and get the asked user score with this:

```
for (const player of players) {
        if (player.username == message.author.tag) {
            message.reply(`Points: - **${player.score}** - `);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to write in this JSON file (when a new user being registered with a score) as I manually did it for testing, but I just can't figure it out how to do it, even with searching on the internet for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [FS.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to write the data to disk.

```js
const FS = require('fs')

// you can't write an object, so first you need to serialize the object
// here, I serialize it as JSON
let data = JSON.stringify(MY_JSON)

// this example uses the sync version for simplicity; FS.writeFile is async
FS.writeFileSync( path, data, 'utf8' )
```

Comment: I'm also the author of the eztxt4fs package on npm, which I created to facilitate using JSON files for storage.